# Is it a bad idea to practicing sing/voice act high and low pitch on the same day near the extremities of your vocal range?

Tags: voice, voice-training

I tried to find a StackExchange community focused on singing and voice acting, but I figure this was the closest I could find.

Since vocal chords are muscle, perhaps they stretch a certain way going high pitch, but maybe the opposite going low pitch? I suppose this can cause strain, but I don't know anything about them but just theorizing. If you do static stretching before weightlifting, I know it loosens the muscles too much to where they aren't as firm so it reduces the power when contracting like for bicep curls, kind of like turning a rubber band (muscle contraction) to string (relaxed/stretched muscles).

From my experience personally, if I try to sing on the same day near the top of my range (excluding falsetto) like up to 2 notes away from the top and then also near the bottom within 2 notes of the bottom, my throat will hurt. However, I haven't tested all scenarios. I've done singing high only on one day (excluding falsetto) without problems, but I haven't tested singing low only on one day.

Comment: Does your throat hurt immediately after you sing those bottom notes, or do you need to sing for a more extended period at the extremes of your voice range (e.g. 5 minutes) before your throat hurts? I find that my throat doesn't hurt when I sing, even after singing an entire song that involves both extremes of my vocal range. (I do tend to get thirsty after singing intensely, though.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci It hurts immediately like within 10 seconds for the bottom notes. For the high notes, in order to get my throat to actually hurt, I have go the highest note in falsetto I can. I forgot to clarify that by the top of the range, I mean top of non-falsetto, not top including falsetto

Answer (score 4):

You might be getting into your [fry register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register) on the low notes, depending on how low you are trying to go. The fry register can be bad for the voice (damaging to the vocal cords.) Try looking up some videos on the fry register to get a better idea if that's what's happening. The pain may have nothing to do with what you're doing in your high range at all.